# Dcrypt and construct all possible words based on provided value in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

This is a questions which i had faced during an interview and not able to solve it. I tried after that but somehow, I messed up the the logic every-time and not able to fix it. Please share the algo and process to achieve it. Here is the problem:

You have an encoding mechanism where A=1, B=2,.....z=26. Now you have to write a JavaScript function which will take a number input and will decode it and will construct all possible values and return it.

Example: Input : 12315
Output: [ABCAE, LCAE, AWAE, AWO, ABCO, LCO]

Here is what i tried but not working as expected.

```
function combinations(string)
{
var result = [];
var loop = function (start,depth,prefix)
{
    for(var i=start; i<string.length; i++)
    {
        var next = prefix+string[i];
        if (depth > 0)
            loop(i+1,depth-1,next);
        else
            result.push(next);
    }
}

for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++)
{
    loop(0,i,'');
}

return result;
}

function dcrypt(code){
   const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
   let result = [];
   for(let i=0; i<code.length; i++){
     result.push(word[i]);
   }
   return combinations(result.join(''));
}

console.log(dcrypt('12315'));
```

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that we really need to see your own effort before we offer help.  I found it interesting, and wrote up what I think is a reasonable solution, but don't really feel like sharing it if you can't show us your own attempt and tell us what went wrong with it.

Comment: Also, why does your output not include `"ABCO"` and `"LCO"`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, Added those two also. Update the question

Comment: @ScottSauyet, Updated my question with one solution which i had tried.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to separate into two steps.  First, split the input digits into all possible sequences of one- or two-digit sets.  Then in a separate step, I would remove those combinations that have items which don't match characters ("27" and above), and map the remaining ones to strings.

This is simpler because the splitting of the digits is easiest expressed with recursion, and we always want our recursive functions to be as simple as possible.  So here is a possible solution:

```js
const splitDigits = ([d1, d2, ...ds]) => 
  d2 == undefined
    ? d1 == undefined ? [[]] : [[d1]]
    : [
        ... splitDigits ([d2, ...ds]) .map (cs => [String (d1), ...cs]),
        ... splitDigits (ds) .map (cs => [String (d1 + d2), ...cs]),
      ]

const decodings = (alpha) => (n) => 
  splitDigits (String (n) .split (''))
    .filter (split => split .every (ch => ch in alpha))
    .map (split => split .map (ch => alpha [ch]) .join(''))


// {"1": "A", "2: "B", ... "26": "Z"}
const alpha = (([...cs] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') => 
  Object .fromEntries (cs .map ((c, i) => [String (i + 1), c]))) ()


console .log (decodings (alpha) (12315))
console .log (decodings (alpha) (12315)) // also takes a number, but not recommended
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`splitDigits` look at the first two characters in the input.  If there are none, we are done, and return an array containing only an empty array.  If there is one, we just return an array with one array containing only that digit.  Otherwise we recur and merge when taking the first digit and also when taking the first two digits.

With this, `12315` would yield `1-2-3-1-5`, `1-2-3-15`, `1-2-31-5`, `1-23-1-5`, `1-23-15`, `12-3-1-5`, `12-3-15`, and `12-31-5`

The `decodings` function will turn its input into an array of digit characters, call `splitDigits`, filter out the results that have out-of-bounds characters (here the two options that contain `31`) and then map the results to their matching characters, joining them back into a single string.

Note that this function also takes the alphabet as a parameter, so that it's slightly more general.  The alphabet is just an object like `{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', ... '26': 'z'}`.  This parameter can be partially applied with the alphabet from the problem if we choose, giving us a function that takes only the test digits.

### Performance

I believe this breakdown makes it easier to think about, and easier to work with.  But if this were a real-world problem, we might also want to think about performance, and there is something fairly ill-performant about the above.  I would stick with it unless it demonstrated a performance issue since I think it breaks the problem down cleanly and the functions are simple enough.

The performance issue can be described by the fact that a larger number, say `86753192261841` has 987 digit splits, but only 12 actual strings, and `86753092260841` also has 987 splits but no actual strings (the zeros don't match the only zeros in the alphabet codes, `10` and `20`.)  So generating all those splits seems overhead.

The fix for this would be for `splitDigits` to check as it went that the digit(s) under test are actually in the alphabet and to stop processing that branch if not.

This is not much harder to code, but the breakdown of responsibilities is much less clear, and `splitDigits` becomes less likely to be useful for other tasks.  But it might be necessary to rein in some complexity.  You can see it by expanding this snippet:

```js
const splitDigits = (alpha) => ([d1, d2, ...ds]) => 
  d2 == undefined
    ? d1 == undefined || !(d1 in alpha) ? [[]] : [[d1]]
    : [
        ... (d1 in alpha ? splitDigits (alpha) ([d2, ...ds]) .map (cs => [d1, ...cs]) : []),
        ... (d1 + d2 in alpha ? splitDigits (alpha) (ds) .map (cs => [d1 + d2, ...cs]) : []),
      ]

const decodings = (alpha) => (n) =>
  splitDigits (alpha) (String (n) .split (''))
    .map (split => split .map (ch => alpha [ch]) .join(''))


// {"1": "A", "2: "B", ... "26": "Z"}
const alpha = (([...cs] = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') => 
  Object .fromEntries (cs .map ((c, i) => [String (i + 1), c])))()

console .log (decodings (alpha) ('12315'))
console .log (decodings (alpha) (12315)) // also takes a number, but not recommended
console .log (decodings (alpha) ('86753192261841'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```